# How to expose a Nodejs app with DDEV web container on local port 80 - 443 with SSL

Tags: node.js, api, port, ddev

Expose nodejs app witch execute on port 3001 on DDEV web container, and access with local port 80 - 443 with SSL for access with **https:myproject.ddev.site** without add any port.

All without create a new container `docker-compose.*.yaml`

Answer (score 3):

To expose 3001 port and work with local ports **80-443**, you have to create an adapter docker-compose file that extends the web container configuration to expose 3001 port and mapping with your local ports **80-443**

docker compose file example

```yaml
version: '3.6'
services:
  web:
    expose:
      - 3001
    environment:
      - HTTP_EXPOSE=${DDEV_MAILHOG_PORT}:8025,80:3001
      - HTTPS_EXPOSE=${DDEV_MAILHOG_HTTPS_PORT}:8025,443:3001
```

Then, run ddev ssh, and execute your app nodejs and open `https://yourproject.ddev.site`

Comment: Thanks for this!  For this to work I think you have to set `router_http_port` and `router_https_port` to something other than 80 and 443 right? Also, you'll want to show people how to start the process, probably with a post-start hook or with a supervisord config as in https://susi.dev/supervisor-ddev